# VueJS/Nuxt.JS how to properly load state from localstorage using "useLocalStorage"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, pinia

I am trying to use `useLocalStorage` from pinia, however on `store's state`, data is not fetched from local storage but getting the default value instead.

Here is the code in my `store` method:

```
import { useLocalStorage } from "@vueuse/core";
export const useTodoStore = defineStore("todos", {
  state: () => {
    console.log("inside state") // not logged
    return {
      todos: useLocalStorage('todos', defautlDataMethod()),
    };
  },
  ...
});

// returns an array of object
function defaultDataMethod() {
}
```

This will always return whatever the value of `defaultData` variable. My expectation is that data from localstorage is fetched. Though if I use `useLocalStorage` in other methods, I can see the stored data without problems.

My alternative for this is to create an action init and run it to my vue

```
import { useLocalStorage } from "@vueuse/core";
export const useTodoStore = defineStore("todos", {
  state: () => {
    console.log("inside state") // not logged
    return {
      todos: [],
    };
  },
  actions: {
    async init() { // run this in vue
      this.todos = useLocalStorage('todos', defautlDataMethod());
    },
  },
  ...
});

// returns an array of object
function defaultDataMethod() {
}
```

For some unknown reasons, I am not able to load the data from init method.

If possible, I want to this solved inside state since this was what it was designed for (i think) but I am open for suggestions

### Note: This needs `@vueuse/core` with `npm i @vueuse/core`

Edit: accessing the localStorage directly also has the same issue(not being used in state)

[github reference](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/309) | [pinia reference](https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/composables.html#Option-Stores) | [vueuse referenace](https://vueuse.org/core/useLocalStorage/#uselocalstorage)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you’re facing might be related to the fact that localStorage is a browser-only feature1. If your application is server-side rendered (SSR), localStorage will not be defined on the server2. This could explain why the data is not fetched from localStorage but the default value is returned instead.

In your alternative approach, you’re trying to use useLocalStorage inside an action. However, useLocalStorage is a Vue Composition API function that returns a reactive ref, and it might not work as expected inside an action.

Here’s a possible solution:

```
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useLocalStorage } from '@vueuse/core';

    export const useTodoStore = defineStore('todos', {
      state: () => ({
        todos: ref([]),
      }),
      actions: {
        init() {
          const storedTodos = useLocalStorage('todos', defaultDataMethod());
          onMounted(() => {
            this.todos = storedTodos.value;
          });
        },
      },
    });
```

In this code, todos is a reactive reference that initially contains an empty array. The init action sets up storedTodos as a local storage item with useLocalStorage. Then, onMounted is used to ensure that this.todos is updated with the value of storedTodos after the component is mounted. This way, the local storage data is fetched when the component is mounted, which should happen on the client side where localStorage is available.

Remember to call the init action in your Vue component:

```
const store = useTodoStore();
store.init();
```

This code should be placed in the setup function of your Vue component.

Please note that this is a workaround and might not be the best solution for your specific use case. It would be best to consider a state management solution that supports server-side rendering, such as Vuex or Pinia with SSR support, if you’re building an SSR application2.

Comment: As I haven't tested it, there may be errors there, but in principle it's supposed to work, I did it in my head.